# How can I calculate identifier TRAM field for this polylines

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, overlay

I would like to have any id field `TRAM`, together lines by group between 2 points, names (PE....). The idea is to write an expression using field calculator to get their id.

- The lines are always connected and touch at start/end points. The X,Y coords of the end point of one line is always equal to the X,Y coords of the next line's start point.
- The `fid` field is not necessarily sequential.
- The lines can have 0, 1 or 2 intersections with features on my point layer which are labeled PE(...).

Next step is use a dissolve algorithm to merge this `"TRAM"` group lines.

This is result I would like.

[image]

EDIT 14 APRIL 2023

I have a point layer "PE", with different code, PE1,PE2,PE3 represent boxes. The line layer "OC", with different sections, always then are touching and intersects with point layer boxes.

I would like to add a field "TRAM" (I use field calculator) to create groups code for example (A,B,C... or other like "fid"  11,11,11,11,15,15,15,18,19) see image. I think that need x,y start and end point coordinates to know is a touch line.

How one image is better than my English words, here image:
[image]

[Here GeoPackage with both layers:](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkY2alhVfunvgVMHAb0DTDyfQS35?e=05cxDd)

[Here similar Question, but not work because I need X,Y start and end points of line for group code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381500/merging-multiple-lines-by-value-field)

Comment: Question unclear. Have a look at aggregate tool.

Comment: If I understand your question, you are trying to split the line layer at every point (PE####), and then merge the lines grouped by this kind of sections generated between to points of the point layer. I guess "TRAM" means "tramo", that's what I call section, my question is: How this groups of lines "tramos" are numbered?

Comment: And, in the picture it looks like there's a branching in the line layer near PE2903, if it's true, this will make it more complex.

Comment: I'm also not very clear with what you're after, and the data in your screenshot has some line segments with duplicated `INI_POINT` coordinates... I get a feeling Aggregate tool or Virtual Layers would be a better tool for what you are after

Comment: I try to explain better. I digitalize lines "Obra_civil_KMZ" with different values (tipus_seccio=S1,S2...) and other fields. These lines represent different pipers and start or end or not intersect with a point layer call "PE".  I need to create a field "TRAM" with common "id value" between these point layers, for in future apply a model with refactorys and dissolve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to group lines that are between points of the PE#### point layer and there's no branching, use this approach:

1. Dissolve the line layer with the [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve) tool. Use the **Keep disjoint features separate** option (available since version 3.26)
2. If your version is lower than 3.26 and there was no **Keep disjoint features separate** option then run the [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) tool on the **Dissolved** layer, else skip this step.
3. Open the [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) tool.

   - Set as **Input layer** the **Dissolved** layer (if you did step 2 it'll be called **Single parts**)

   - Set the **Output geometry type** parameter to **Line**

   - Click the [image: 4] button of the **Geometry expression** parameter, then go to the **Function editor** tab and add a file with the [image: 5] button. Now in this new file paste this code, and click the [image: 6] **Save and Load Functions** button:

```py
@qgsfunction(args=-1, group='Arrays', referenced_columns=[])
def array_zip(arrays, feature, parent):
    return list(map(list, zip(*arrays)))
```

this code defines one function that will be used by the following  expression.
Return to the **Expression** tab and paste the following expression, remember to change **'Point layer name/id'** with your values, click ok and run:

```
collect_geometries(
    with_variable(
        name:='section',
        value:=array_sort(
            with_variable(
                name:='line_vertices',
                value:=array_foreach(
                    array:=geometries_to_array(nodes_to_points($geometry)),
                    expression:=array(x(@element), y(@element))
                ),
                expression:=array_foreach(
                    array:=overlay_intersects(
                        layer:='Point layer name/id', -- replace here with your values
                        expression:=array($x, $y)
                    ),
                    expression:=array_find(
                        array:=@line_vertices,
                        value:=@element
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        expression:=with_variable(
            name:='substrings',
            value:=array_zip(
                array_slice(@section, 0, -2),
                array_slice(@section, 1, -1)
            ),
            expression:=array_foreach(
                array:=@substrings,
                expression:=make_line(
                    array_slice(
                        geometries_to_array(nodes_to_points($geometry)),
                        @element[0],
                        @element[1]
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Finally, but it looks that the lines are still merged, this happens because it's a multiline geometry. So run the [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) algorithm in this layer (**Modified geometries**) and you'll be done.

Answer (score 0):

Dissolve all lines, then split them at the points. You can do it in 3 simple steps:

1. [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdissolve) the layer
2. At each point, create a small auxiliary line, perpendicular to the initial line. Use [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression) on the point layer with this expression:

   ```
    extend(
        make_line (
            $geometry,
            project (
                $geometry, 
                1,  -- use a small value
                radians(
                    90+line_interpolate_angle( 
                        overlay_nearest ('Dissolved',$geometry)[0],
                        line_locate_point (overlay_nearest ('Dissolved',$geometry)[0], $geometry)
                    )))),1,0) -- use a small value
   ```
3. Use [Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgissplitwithlines): use the dissolved layer for `Input layer` and the auxiliary lines from step 2 as `Split layer`. Now create a new field with the Field calculator expression `$id`.

*Small, auxiliary black lines at each point, used to split the dissolved line:*
[image]